# Mysql query of Sum of each department salary

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table in my database my database structure like this

[image]

My two table value like this

[image]

I want like this

[image]

Please help me anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select d.department_id,d.department_name,sum(e.salary)
from department d inner join employee e on d.department_id=e.department_id
group by d.department_id,d.department_name
```